# Getting Google Visualization (GoogleVisualr gem) working with Pdfkit - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-visualization, pdfkit

I am trying to create a pdf export of an Org Chart that is generated using the google_visualr gem.

(rails 4.2.1 / pdfkit 0.7.0 / google_visualr 2.4.0 / wkhtmltopdf binary 0.9.0)

controller:

```
  def org_chart
   data_table = GoogleVisualr::DataTable.new
   data_table.new_column('string', 'Name'   )
   data_table.new_column('string', 'Manager')
   data_table.new_column('string', 'ToolTip')
   data_table.add_rows(
    [
      [ {:v => 'Mike', :f => 'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'   }, ''    , 'The President' ],
      [ {:v => 'Jim' , :f => 'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President<div>'}, 'Mike', 'VP'            ],
      [ 'Alice'  , 'Mike', ''           ],
      [ 'Bob'    , 'Jim' , 'Bob Sponge' ],
      [ 'Carol'  , 'Bob' , ''           ]
    ]
  )
  opts   = { :allowHtml => true }
  @chart = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::OrgChart.new(data_table, opts)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      html = render_to_string(layout: false, action: "org_chart", formats: :pdf)
      kit = PDFKit.new(html, :orientation => 'Landscape', :page_size => "A3")
      kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/pdf/pdf.css"
      send_data(kit.to_pdf, filename: "org chart", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline')
    end
  end
end
```

org_chart.pdf.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <%= open("https://www.google.com/jsapi").read.html_safe.force_encoding("UTF-8") %>
</script>
<h1>Org Chart</h1>



<div id="chart"></div>
<%= render_chart @chart, "chart" %>
```

This produces a pdf with just the h1 Org Chart text.

Logging the generated html string produces: [gist](https://gist.github.com/castlese/8b1571ed9e6c80a8ad1d)

In the html version of the chart, there are dynamically generated javascript files added to the head, for example https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=orgchart&async=2. I don't think these are being loaded in the pdf version, hence the chart is failing to render.

Has anyone come across this before - any advice for a good way to dynamically load these javascript files?

### Update:

I've got this working by adding the javascript files to the pdf view as follows:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "#{root_url}assets/application.js" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=orgchart&async=2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/e4daa89e21758ca575303e781d536a37/format+en,default+en,ui+en,orgchart+en.I.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<h1>Org Chart</h1>



<div id="chart"></div>
<%= render_chart @chart, "chart" %>
```

However, this is a bit hacky and only applies to the orgchart. I wonder how to get the javascript files to add dynamically.

Also, it's giving me threading issues in production which I'm still working on (I'm using multiple workers on unicorn in development so it works there)